# Android TextView Vertical Padding Between Lines in Compose

Tags: android

I'm looking to add vertical spacing between my lines in an Android Compose app. You can see the issue I'm having in my TextView when the text wraps in the image here:

[image]

It looks like you used to be able to do this in the old XML system by using the TextView function `setLineSpacing`, but looking through the docs for Compose's TextView, I can't find an equivalent. Am I just missing something?